# Navigation Option Within Web Templates and Onet.xml

Tags: 2010, navigation, web-template, onet

I have created a web template which deploys and creates subsite when used.

Problem : I am trying to get the navigation setting to work as the image below

[image: Required Navigation]

The current Onet.XML being used to create the web template is shown below. Which properties need to be set to achieve the above navigation?

[image]

This current onet.xml gives the following results.

[image: Current Navigation Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Use ShowSiblings property :

```
<Property Key="ShowSiblings" Value="true"/>
```

If set the TRUE, the outcome is the same options as the “Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings” option in the user interface (second option from the picture below). Note that the IncludeSubSites and IncludePages parameters also affects to outcome.

And InheritCurrentNavigation
This controls the inheritance of the current navigation. If set the true, we would get the same results as by selecting the "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" from the user interface (the first option from the picture below)

```
  <Property Key="InheritCurrentNavigation" Value="true"/>
```

[link to source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2007/03/23/controlling-navigation-options-from-the-onet-xml.aspx)